# Making a capital letter with a shift modifier press and hold option with Keyboard Maestro

Tags: keyboard-maestro

I have been using Autoit for years and I have just discovered Keyboard Maestro for Mac and it's AWESOME!

Here is my problem. I need to simulate pressing the SHIFT + 1 key. Here are the steps

1. Press and Hold the Shift Key
2. Push and Release the 1 Key
3. Release the Shift Key

Pretty simple but for some reason it is not working. I am testing it out with the letter "a" instead of 1 because if it worked then it would create the capital letter "A".

How can I get this to produce a capital letter A by using the Shift Modifier?

Here is a screenshot of my macro

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In "Simulate Keystroke", just hold down Shift+1. It will put that in as the keystroke combo, not the ! symbol.

[Shift-1 example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4Xd6.png)